# Vps Can't Login

Tags: bash, authentication, error-handling, vps

when I was in / root / I made a mistake until a bash error occurred by finding more or less "bash error / bin / bash not file or directory" then many functions did not work. I then log out and when I access the vps again with ssh suddenly I can't log in with the password statement incorrectly. I tried to access via the console provided by the service provider. but when logging in, the word "login blablabla shell" appears. I can't do anything after that. how to fix it?

I want to try rebooting the vps but worry when booting error and causing stuck

Answer (score 0):

This is more a question for 'Superuser', but if you are in trouble like this, such a referral is generally not helpful, and therefore this answer, which will not make you happy.

In general, what you have reduced to 'blablabla' is the important part of the error message.So we cannot deduce what happened from the error message. That means that no-one can get a login-shell. Even worse: most systems use bash-scripts during their start-up phase. So the system will not start-up anymore.

Worse even: you seem to have deleted much of the contents of `/bin` and `/usr/bin`. That makes it difficult to recover anything. So now your server is effectively unusable.

There are now a but few options:

1) Re-install the server. Because it is lost and you cannot access it anymore.

2) try to recover data. This depends a bit on your server provider. If you are able to boot off an ISO image, you may try a live-CD and scp the data to a working system before you reinstall the system. You may need console access for this, again depending on your provider's set-up

3) Try to re-animate the dead server using a recovery ISO image.
This is not for the faint of heart. It requires a lot of knowledge.

In any case: if you succeed to reanimate the server, you will not want to run production on it, unless it is absolutely critical. Although it might look stable-ish, you will encounter problems. So unless the one of the four horsemen prevents you, reinstall the server.